# How do I apply colours to a string in a GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview

```
private string ColouredString(string input)
{
    //I would like to apply red color to string 'nve'
    string nve = "No Value";
    return nve;
}
```

How do I apply a color to a string in a GridView?

Comment: A color to a string? You mean a color to a `label` or a `textBox` content or something like that, right?

Comment: The string can not be colored itself. It's a formatting attribute of the control that shows the string.

Comment: @Leito The string is just by itself, I want it colored, and I'm using it in a gridview.

Answer (score 4):

String is a collection of characters in memory. It doesn't have any color information embedded in it.
You need to set the color on the control that is displaying the string.

For example if it is a TextBox control it might have a ForeColor property or FontColor property, etc.
Check the properties of the control/surface you're showing string on.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using the string in a gridview, does this mean that I have to edit the information in the gridview?

Comment: Yes gridview cell holds the property of setting some color to its content. Just like in excel sheet.

Comment: But the problem is, I'll be importing a file to the database, and the contents of the file will be displayed in the gridview, if the data of the file is empty/incorrect, it'll then show string nve, and I want string nve to be red because it will be more obvious to the user.

Comment: http://blog.devexperience.net/en/5/Change_background_color_of_GridView%27s_Rows.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to colour only that particular value if it is empty?

Answer (score 1):

Add an event to your `dataGridView` for `dataGridView_CellValueChanged` :

```
private void dataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString())) {

        // Display error string in cell
        dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = "No Value";
        // Set color to red
        dataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it's not working, see, I have a method called ErrorMessage to check if the GridView cell is empty, it will display the message "No value entered" I want this "No value entered" to be red color =/

Comment: @Terence What do you mean it's not working? Did you try adding the event as I said in my answer? The method you wrote in your question is not enough, you have at some point to modify the dataGridView content.

Comment: I don't have dataGridView_CellvalueChanged, but I have a method:       private string ErrorMessage(string input)
        
            {


                {
                       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                        return input;                }
          
               return "No value entered!";            }

Comment: You **have to** create the `dataGridView_CellValueChanged` event and bind it to your dataGridView. If you don't know how to do that, post another question on SO.